# How Can I upload my laravel 8 and tailwind css based application to cpanel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, tailwind-css

I am new to laravel . thanks for the help .
I have build an application using laravel 8 (with jetstream+livewire) and tailwind CSS.
It works perfectly in my local machine . by running :

```
php artisan serve
```

But when I upload the site/codes to the live server , it does not get the proper styles that i defined in **'`tailwind.config.js`'** file.

what i get is only the css that can be generated from cdn (I am not using tailwind cdn , i am sure ) .
For more clear question : I get only the compiled css from
`app.css` file. I do not get the extended feature that I enabled in ***`tailwind.config.js`***
file. such as , I do not get the output for this in live server (codes from my tailwin.config.js):

```
variants: {
    extend: {
        translate: ['group-hover'],
        scale: ['group-hover'],
        transitionProperty: ['group-hover'],
        display: ['group-hover'],
    },
},
```

But in my local machine, everything is perfect.
I have uploaded it in 000webhostapp. by following [this guideline](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-on-000webhost/127323)
**I did not include the node_modules folder in the upload**

for any help , thanks in advance.

Comment: did you run the command ```npm run dev``` or ```npm run prod``` ?
because I understand that the generate file will be read by laravel later, not read through node_modules folder,   https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel

Comment: I understand from this tutorial https://medium.com/teknomuslim/getting-started-tailwind-ui-with-laravel-482f65fd6ef0  ,  https://indocoder.com/tips-trick-laravel/laravel-7-menggunakan-tailwindcss/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are serving the public folder and not the root of your Laravel project.  You should not be able to see `public` in your URLs.

This will impact the path to the css file.  You should verify loading of all resources by looking in the developer tools, networking tab.

Comment: Thank you for your reply . But I am not sure about what you said , can you please elaborate it a bit more ? Thank you once again.